# Unable to update or delete rows in database using codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, crud

I am new to code-igniter, and I am facing unknown issues in updation and deletion of `rows` in my `database`. My code for Controller is :

```
 <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Nhome extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->Model('N_model');
        $data['r'] = $this->N_model->getdata();
        $this->load->view('Homeview',$data);
    }
    public function edit()
    {
        $id = $this->input->get('id');
        $this->load->Model('N_model');
        $data['s'] = $this->N_model->editdata();
        $this->load->view('Neditview',$data);
    }
    public function loadEdit()
    {
        $id = $this->input->get('id');
        $this->load->view('Neditview');
    }
    public function insertdata()
    {
        $eID = isset($_POST['Id'])?$_POST['Id']:'';

        $arr['Name'] = $_POST['Name'];
        $arr['Gender'] = $_POST['Gender'];
        $arr['Email'] = $_POST['Email'];

        $this->load->Model('N_model');
        $res = $this->N_model->updatedata($arr , $eID);
        if($res){
            header('location:'.base_url()."index.php/Nhome/".$this->index());
        }
    }
    public function delete(){
        $this->load->Model('N_model');
        $id = $this->input->get('Id');
        $this->N_model->deletedata($id);
        $this->index();
    }
}
```

and my code for model is  :

```
<?php
class N_Model extends CI_Model{

    public $Id;
    public $Name;
    public $Gender;
    public $Email;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getdata()
    {
        $va = $this->db->get('newprac');
        $res = $va->result();
        return $res;
    }
    public function editdata($id)
    {
        $vr = $this->db->where('Id',$id);
        return $vr;
    }
    public function updatedata($data , $id){
        $this->db->where('newprac.Id',$id);
        $res = $this->db->update('newprac', $data);
        return $res;
    }
    public function deletedata($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('newprac.id',$id);
        $this->db->delete('newprac');
        if($this->db->affected_rows()>0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else { return false; }
    }
}
```

Comment: So,What Difficulty Are You Facing? Any Error Coming? If Yes, Please Provide That Error Too.

Comment: no there are literally no errors.. i think it is some logical error, as while editing the row, the editview appears and i can also enter information, after pressing submit button, it redirects to home page.. but no data has been updated or even deleted. can you please tell me why is it so?

Comment: If you passing true or false from your model then why not you check from your controller that it is true if true then you call view page or you passing the same page. and also can you please die in your model and echo $this->db->last_query(); and see what query you are generated and run this query in your phpmyadmin  and then you understand what happens.

Comment: Could you please die in your delete controller and echo $this->input->get('Id'); and see what happen do you get id blank?

Answer (score 0):

Change

`$this->db->where('newprac.id',$id)`

to

`$this->db->where('id',$id);`

Comment: it didnt work. i think its some logical error. can you please resolve it out?

Comment: What is the name of the variable you get with GET id or Id? In your controller you use both. Maybe this is help. Change $this->input->get('Id') to $this->input->get('id');

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your code to:

```
$this->db->where('id',$id)->update('newprac', $data);
```

Comment: i have tried it, it didnt work either. its not about simplification. i cant find any error. its just some logical problem

Answer (score 0):

Replace your controller by this code. Becuase I think you passing data as a post method so you should use post when you retrieve data.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Nhome extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->Model('N_model');
        $data['r'] = $this->N_model->getdata();
        $this->load->view('Homeview',$data);
    }
    public function edit()
    {
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        $this->load->Model('N_model');
        $data['s'] = $this->N_model->editdata();
        $this->load->view('Neditview',$data);
    }
    public function loadEdit()
    {
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        $this->load->view('Neditview');
    }
    public function insertdata()
    {
        $eID = isset($_POST['Id'])?$_POST['Id']:'';

        $arr['Name'] = $_POST['Name'];
        $arr['Gender'] = $_POST['Gender'];
        $arr['Email'] = $_POST['Email'];

        $this->load->Model('N_model');
        $res = $this->N_model->updatedata($arr , $eID);
        if($res){
            header('location:'.base_url()."index.php/Nhome/".$this->index());
        }
    }
    public function delete(){
        $this->load->Model('N_model');
        $id = $this->input->post('Id');
        $this->N_model->deletedata($id);
        $this->index();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to debug using Chrome debugger. You might get the exact error in debugger. I suggest you to try once let me know the error name.